# Could not authorize you from LDAP because "No such address or other socket error."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

After update my gitlab instance to 6.8.1 the ldap login stopped to work.

When I try to login, I saw the error: Could not authorize you from LDAP because "No such address or other socket error." (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttVgE.png)

Here the rake env:info and check: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7398134/

The rake gitlab:ldap:check --trace:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7398270/

Let me know if I can provide other specific logs or make my question more clear.

Comment: Reported an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6924

Comment: Reported an issue in GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/258

Answer (score 2):

It feels like someone messed up with the DNS confs.
After fix the local DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf, the gitlab instance starts to see the local servers again and the authentication starts to work again. Not a gitlab issue.

Fixed.